# Creating a countdown timer and update MySQL table column value on start and stop of timer

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I am working on a project in which one of the functionality needs to add start time and finish time of an event. I want to change the content of front-end based on start and stop of timer and with that want to made some change in MySQL table row.

```
For ex:
Start : 9/7/2018 00:00:00 PM    Stop: 12/7/2018 00:00:00 PM

File Name: A.html
//Content change with time
1. Before Starting Timer : Upcoming Event
2. After Timer Starts: Ongoing Event
3. After Timer Stops: Event Finished


MySQL
Table Name: Event
Column Name: is_active
//is_active value
4. Before Starting Timer: Upcoming
5. On Timer Starts: Ongoing
6. On Timer Stops: Finished
```

And I want to fetch the values Upcoming, Ongoing, Finished from the MySQL column is_active and then want to show it on A.html in points 1, 2 and 3.
Also I want to show a countdown timer on the A.html page.
I am using Node.js in back-end and MySQL as database. 
Hope I've made my problem clear. SQL Event or triggers should be applied in this if I'm not wrong.

```
For better understanding it is same as E-commerce flash sales. Before 
starting sale "coming soon", as sale starts " Buy", as sale finishes "sold 
out" and accordingly change in database and show the countdown timer like sale finishes in "XX-XX-XX" time.
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: SQL triggers is almost always not the answer as they're very limited. Instead have SQL logic in your query that combines any discount factors or applies any limiting scopes based on date ranges.

Comment: Can you please explain with it example?